# jquery ajax working fine only without server hosting

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have got following code :

```
$('span').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('class'),

        success: function (data) {
           $('#articleContent').html($(data).find('p').html());

        }
    });

});
```

It works fine when i access to page by filesystem `file:///...`
Problem occurs when i want to share that page and i host it via IIS express ( i just copied page directory inside other aspx page folder directory ), then success function fires but `data.html()` returns null.

Do you have any ideas what is the problem ?

Comment: make sure url path is correct for the server...

Comment: What is the URL of the server hosting ? What is inside the 'class' attribute ?

Comment: well, ajax stays javascript. I believe your client (running that ajax script) does not have public access to where the file is on your server

Comment: thanks for responses , data and all settings are fine becouse `$('#articleContent').load($(this).attr('class'));` works fine , although i dont want simple load because i need to pick some informations form there, not all

Comment: Can you log the "data" variable and make sure it looks OK? If the data itself is fine, there may be a problem with the MIME type of the reply.

Comment: The url is fine since the `success` callback fires; however, whereas the `.load()` method will only use the html data type, `$.ajax()` doesn't necessarily do that, but rather makes a 'best guess'. `console.log(data)` will show you exactly how the data is returned

Comment: Ok i logged data and it looks exacly like requested page `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` etc etc

Comment: and the problem occurs even with dataType :"html" or "text"

Answer (score 0):

Is the IIS domain different than the domain the JS is hosted at, because if so, the Same Origin Policy will prevent you from accomplishing this. Given the circumstances you described I think this is your problem.

The Same Origin Policy is a security restriction to prevent XSS. Supposedly there are workarounds using Server-Side.

Perhaps if you clarified your objective I could help you in more detail?

Comment: It is all on my local computer (server and page) and it works in local network